# validate a field in function of the presence of another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have 2 fields:

```
attr_accessible :in_home #=> boolean, setted at false by default
mount_uploader :carousel_picture, CarouselUploader#=>an image picture with CarrierWave + Rmagick. Nil by default
attr_accessible :carousel_picture
```

My question is: I try to validate the fact that when the user checks the "in_home" checkbox, he should have uploaded a "carousel_picture"

```
    validates :in_home, :if => Proc.new { |obj| (obj.in_home && obj.carousel_picture?) == true }, :presence => {:message => "You should upload a carousel picture to set the item in the home page."},
```

But this validation doesn't work, I can create an object with the in_home checked and the carousel_picture empty.

When I try after in my rails console:

```
1.9.3p362 :001 > obj = MyObject.all.last
  => #<Gift id: 22, name: "foo", created_at: "2013-04-02 09:13:00", updated_at: "2013-04-02 09:13:00", carousel_picture: nil, in_home: true>
1.9.3p362 :002 > obj.in_home && obj.carousel_picture?
  => false
```

So I think there is something that I don't understand in how I do a validation of a field. Any help would be useful!
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try this, `validates_presence_of :carousel_picture, :if => lambda {|obj| obj.in_home == "true"}`

Comment: Thank you it works. But it is true without quotes ;-). Add it as answer that I can valid your help. Thank you

Comment: oops. Yeah you are right. True without quotes. I posted this as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
validates_presence_of :carousel_picture, :if => lambda {|obj| obj.in_home == true}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar recently, I think the below code should work for you:

```
validates :carousel_picture, :presence => { :if => Proc.new { |a| a.in_home? }, message: "You should upload a carousel picture to set the item in the home page." }
```

Comment: yes it also works, but written with a good brace:   validates :carousel_picture, :presence => {:if => Proc.new { |a| a.in_home? }, message: "You should upload a carousel picture to set the item in the home page." }